# vb how to let btn know textbox value for increase and decrease?

Tags: vb.net, button, visual-studio-2015, textbox

[image]

how i let my button know my text box value. i want to do is let my button know about my value when i insert 10 if i click + button will be 11 if i click - button will be 9 what should i do?

here is my addbtn code

```
i = i + 1
    txtqty.Text = CStr(i)
```

this is my decrease btn code

```
i = i - 1
    txtqty.Text = CStr(i)
```

Comment: You know there is a NumericUpDown already in your toolbox, right?

Comment: ？？ i was facing is if i enter 12 when i click + button it will become 1 when click - button will become -1 but @Steve have help solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the content of the TextBox to an integer, perform your calculation and then reassign the calculated value back to the textbox

```
Dim value as Int
If Int32.TryParse(txtqty.Text, value) Then
   value = value + 1
   txtqty.Text = value.ToString()
else
   MessageBox.Show("The textbox doesn't contain a valid number")
End If
```

Of course when you deal with user input you should take extra care on checking if the input is good for the task that you want to perform. Thus I have used [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) that return false if the content of the textbox is not a valid integer number.